# How to add a second DB2 instance in Data Studio 4.1

Tags: db2, db2-luw, ibm-data-studio

In the past, when I used the Control Center + DB2 express 9.7, I could see all instances:

[image]

Now with Data Studio 4.1 + DB2 Express C 11.1 I can't see the second instance. Why?

I tried to follow this procedure but it did not work:

1. Install db2 express C v11.1 (name instance =  DB2, port = 50000,
   user = db2admin)
2. Create a database SAMPLE
3. Install Data Studio 4.1.2 Client
4. Create the second instance (command --> db2icrt -u db2admin DB2INST2)
5. Change DB2INSTANCE to point to the second instance (command --> set db2instance = DB2INST2)
6. Create a new database SAMPLE_inst2 (command line)
7. Connect to SAMPLE_inst2 (command line)
8. Restart Data Studio

but still I don't see the second instance (DB2INST2), I see only the first instance (DB2).
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you just have to add the second database - via the add database icon in the database explorer. 
It seems you expect to get it automatically but DataStudio uses JDBC connections and not the admin node cfg etc.
The database SAMPLE in inst2 is also not cataloged in the first instance and i.e. cannot be connected from an instance 1 command line.

Summary: Define JDBC connection for all databases you want to access.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply. The problem is: when I add the second database - via the add database icon with the second instance, Data Studio creates the second DB in the first instance (not in a separate instance), and if I try to connect to it, return error "database not found"

Comment: When adding a database you have to specify a port. This port needs to be the communication port of the second instance. This means every instance has a port assigned for communication from remote (or from other instances). You might need to specify one if you have created the instance. Set SVCENAME in the DBM CFG to a port name and map this mane in etc/services to a port. After that ensure db2set DB2COMM=TCPIP is set.

Comment: thanks!!! I have solved!!!
In the etc/services there wasn't name service and port for second instance